# viber href link works on PC, not on mobile

Tags: html, href, anchor, viber

I have html  href link like this

```
 <a href="viber://chat/?number=+995 555 55 55 55">
```

its working properly on computer, but not on the mobile, when I click the link on my phone, I see a line near the tab, therefore I know it knows its a link to somethere, but it is not working, why?

Comment: That app has to register the url handler

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Viber on your phone must do something. Nothing really you can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after hours of research, I found another thread on stackoverflow and made it work. replacing '+' before number with %2b works like a charm

```
 <a href="viber://chat/?number=%2B995555555555">
```